# Cgroup swap accounting

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cgroups

I'm trying to enable cgroup swap accounting on a Google instance that has ubuntu-1204-precise-v20141028 deployed. I've tried the usual addition of cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1 into "/etc/default/grub" but it appears that only the memory controller is enabled and not the swap (I checked the available metrics are in the pseudo-file memory.stat). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've contacted google and said that it's a problem with the Ubuntu image, which is not fully supported yet by GCE